# Clicking the button should change all the links on the page to the linkStyles class on the css

Tags: javascript

I want the button click to toggle the linkStyles class from the css to all the 
a" tag links on the page. The button click should only apply styles to the links on the page.

```js
var $ = function (id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
};
var changeLinks = function () {
    document.getElementsByTagName("A").classList.toggle("linkStyle");
}
window.onload = function () {
    $("links").addEventListener("click", linkStyles);
}
```

```css
.linkStyle{
 font-weight: bold;
 text-decoration-style: dotted;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <main>
        <div>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <a href="#">consectetur adipisicing elit</a>. Perspiciatis magni reprehenderit quibusdam ipsam eius odit iste consequatur necessitatibus voluptatibus deserunt maxime esse, similique, cupiditate facere quis <a href="#">quos id</a> delectus est.</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur <a href="#">adipisicing elit</a>. Autem magni voluptatibus tempore aut corrupti, ducimus optio consequuntur. Quasi debitis a dicta natus <a href="#">voluptas</a> alias ea, quis excepturi ut, eius accusantium.</p>
        </div>
        <section>
            <button type="button" id="links">Change Links Button</button>
        </section>
    </main>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `querySelectorAll("a")` to get all `a` elements, and then iterate over then using `for of`:

```js
var changeLinks = function() {
  for (var el of document.querySelectorAll("a"))
    el.classList.toggle("linkStyle");
}
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("links").addEventListener("click", changeLinks);
}
```

```css
.linkStyle { font-weight: bold; text-decoration-style: dotted; }
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <a href="#">consectetur adipisicing elit</a>. Perspiciatis magni reprehenderit quibusdam ipsam eius odit iste consequatur necessitatibus voluptatibus deserunt maxime esse, similique, cupiditate facere quis <a href="#">quos id</a>  delectus est.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur <a href="#">adipisicing elit</a>. Autem magni voluptatibus tempore aut corrupti, ducimus optio consequuntur. Quasi debitis a dicta natus <a href="#">voluptas</a> alias ea, quis excepturi ut, eius accusantium.</p>
<button type="button" id="links">Change Links Button</button>
```